# how to disable focus in textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget, I have a drop down menu depending on the amount of data on the map. But the problem is that each of these drop-down menus has an active focus. And I want this focus to be inactive for everyone. But the problem is that this widget has a mandatory focus setting and I can't pick it up, I just need to turn it off! Does anyone know how to disable it in all items on my list ??Thenks)

```
Widget _buildAdditionFields(SimpleOrderStates state) {
if (state.isAdditionsProgress) {
  return const Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(Margins.small),
    child: PlatformProgressIndicator(),
  );
} else {

  var name = state.additionEntity?.name ?? '';
  var options = state.additionEntity?.getAddition(0)?.dropdownItems;

     var list = state.additionEntity?.selectedVariants
      .mapIndexed(
          (index, addition) =>  Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Margins.little),
            child: _buildDropdownField(
              text: addition!["aditionVariontName"],
              enabled: true,
              progress: false,
              dropdownOptions: [],
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
              applySelected: true,
              action: SvgPicture.asset(Img.dropdownArrow),
              labelText: addition!["additionName"],
              dropdownItemSelected: (item) {
                BlocProvider.of<SimpleOrderBloc>(context).add(
                    SimpleOrderDropdownMenuAdditionItemSelectedEvent(item));
              },
              textChanged: (text) {}
          )),


     ).toList()

  return Column(
    children: list ?? [],
  );
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just after the list is created add

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Or

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

Comment: An error occurred. "This expression is of type "void", so its value cannot be used. (Documentation) Try to make sure you're using the correct API, there may be a function or call that returns an invalid value that you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables that may also be invalid "

Comment: You probably added it in the wrong place

Comment: yes, I already understood it, but I found a  new problem, the focus is removed from all the widgets on the page, and has only in this list

Comment: I didnt get you. You wanted to turn off all focus right?

Comment: What is applyselected key in your list? Turn it to false if thats the focus to textfield

Comment: yes, but of all the list items "list". And I have other dropdowns on the page. And when I want to enter something in them, there is an immediate focus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245889/discussion-between-andrii-havrylyak-and-kaushik-chandru).